# Winsock2 tcp/ip - some data packets are ignored probably due to null terminator from the previous packet

Tags: c++, string, sockets, winsock2

I wrote a simple client-server program. Network.h is a header file which uses Winsock2.h (TCP/IP mode) to create socket, accept/connect in blocking mode, send/recv in non-blocking mode. I made it so that the function `string TNetwork::Recv(int size)` will return the string "Nothing" if it gets WSAWOULDBLOCK error (no data is received yet)

Here is my main function:

```
int main(){
    string Ans;
    TNetwork::StartUp(); //WSA start up, etc
    cin >> Ans;
    if (Ans == "0"){ // 0 --> server
        TNetwork::SetupAsServer(); //accept connection (in blocking mode!)
        while (true){
            TNetwork::Send("\nAss" + '\0'); //without null terminator, the client may read extra bytes, causing undefined behavior (?)
            TNetwork::Send("embly" + '\0');
            cin >> Ans;
        }
    }
    else{ // others --> regard Ans as IP address. e.g. I can type "127.0.0.1"
        TNetwork::SetupAsClient(Ans);
        string Rec;
        while (true){
            Rec = TNetwork::Recv(1000);
            if (Rec != "Nothing"){
                cout << Rec;
            }
        }
    }
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Supposedly, the client would print "Assembly" when connected, and when the server enters anything to its console window. Sometimes, though, the client would only print out "\nAss" in the console without the "embly.

To my understanding, TCP/IP ensures all data to be sent and in the correct order, so I guess what happens is that both packets arrive at the same time, which happen quite often over the unstable internet. And due to this null terminator, the client would ignore the "embly", since the Recv() function stopped reading when it hits a null terminator.

So, how can I ensure that the client will always read all data packets correctly?

Comment: If there is a solution to send packets without the null terminator, somehow, I won't mind as well. I would change any part of the code if it works. I'm relatively new to winsock2 (as well as socket programming) so I probably have some basic mistakes.

Comment: Null termination and TCP have nothing to do with each other. You're barking up the wrong tree here. The TCP send and receive APIs take pointer and length arguments and they place no interpretation on the contents whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the network stack will send the data in the correct order and doesn't care what termination type you use.  This has to do with how you're receiving and processing the data *stream* (note: not packets, **stream**).  If you receive all 11 bytes and print it to the screen, the *print* function will stop when it reaches the zero, but the rest of the data is still there.

Note: since it's a stream, what happens if you received only 10 bytes of data from the stream?  You need to scan what you receive for the zero to know if you've received a full "zero-terminated string" if that's how you want to communicate your data.

EDIT: Also, I don't think `"\nAss" + '\0'` is doing what you think it is.  Instead of adding a 0 character to the end of the string (which already has one, by the way), it's adding 0 to your string pointer.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistakes! Earlier, I tried to print out the *char variable that I pass to recv and without sending the null terminator, I would receive random bytes, but I didn't realize that it's from the print function, so I thought winsock needs a null terminator XP . Also I should have known that all string objects have null terminator already, but I missed this fact. Everything is clear now :D .

Answer (score 0):

As @mark points out, TCP is all about streams, not packets.  TCP takes care of ensuring that data is reliably transmitted from A to B and that the data is delivered to the consumer in the order in which it was transmitted.  Yes, the data is packetized on the wire, but the TCP stack on the system takes those packets and builds the stream which it makes available to you through the `recv()` function.  The TCP stack handles out-of-order data, missing data, and duplicated data such that by the time your application sees it, the stream is a mirror-copy of when the sender sent.

To properly receive TCP data, you will typically need some kind of loop that reads data from the socket when it becomes available.  The way I normally do this is to have a thread that is dedicated to servicing the socket.  In the thread function is a loop that reads data from the socket when it becomes available and is idle otherwise.  This loop reads data into a buffer of, say, 1 KB.  Once the data is received from the socket into this buffer, the buffer is copied to another thread for processing.  In the thread function for the processing thread is a loop that receives the 1 KB buffers from the socket thread and adds them to the back end of a master buffer of, say, 1 MB.  The processing thread then processes the messages out of this master buffer and makes them available to the application.

For a simple demo application, two threads may be overkill.  The two threads I've described could be certainly be combined into one, but for my application, it is more efficient to have two threads and take advantage of the multiple cores on my system.  The point is, if you're going to have a front-end UI, there's not going to be a way around using at least one thread and still have the UI be responsive.

One other thing.  There are two commonly-used mechanisms for protocol design.  You're using one, namely, a marker (e.g., a null terminator, etc.) to signal the begin/end of a message.  I don't prefer this mechanism mainly because the marker may actually need to be part of the message at some point.  The other mechanism is to have a header on each message that tells, at a minimum, how long the message is.  I prefer this mechanism and include in my headers a sync word and the message type as well.  For example,

```
struct Header
{
    __int16 _sync;  // a hex pattern, e.g., 0xABCD
    __int16 _type;
    __int32 _length;
}
```

That's a total of 8 bytes.  So when processing from the master buffer, I read the first 8 bytes, verify the sync word, and get the length.  I determine if there are 'length' bytes available in the master buffer.  If not, I have to wait until the socket thread provides me more data before checking again.  If so, I extract 'length' bytes from the master buffer and pass that to an object created according to the specified type, which knows how to interpret that particular message.  Then repeat.

As I mentioned, I use a master buffer of 1 MB or so.  As messages are processed, it is important to remove them from the master buffer so there is additional space available for *new* data on the back end.  This involves simply copying the unprocessed data, if any, to the beginning of the buffer.  In cases where data comes in faster than you can process it, the master buffer may need the ability to resize itself to accommodate the additional data.

I hope that's not overwhelming.  Start simple and add as you go.

Comment: Thanks, this is a very good answer too! My approach is almost the same as what you described, except I used a string as the master buffer, which causes problems upon receiving null terminator.

Thanks for pointing out the use of headers in messages. I should consider using that in future applications.